# 404 error when calling Spring controller method from Angular $http

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have been trying to run a sample Single Page Application that uses Spring 4.2.5 along with AngularJs. I am trying to call one of my methods in Controller from Angular's `$http` service.

**Inside some controller:**

```
$scope.goTosearchList = function() {
        $http.get("/rest/getSearchList").success(function(data){
            $scope.data=data;
            alert("success "+data);
        })
        $location.path("/rest/searchList");
    };
```

**Trying to catch this request in a controller:**

```
@Controller

public class MyPortController {

    @Autowired
    DatabaseDao dao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/getSearchList",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void searchbyid() {

        System.out.println("hello, we r in java");
        dao.databaseConnect();

    }

}
```

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MyPort</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Here is my spring servlet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mmt.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
   <!--  <bean id="searchbyid" class="com.mmt.dao.DatabaseDao">
    </bean> -->

    </beans>
```

Issue may sound a bit naive, but I do am not able to find a way out. Please help me.

Comment: Try changing the request path to localhost:8080/rest/getSearchList (if you are running it on localhost).

Comment: Do you have other working handlers ?

Comment: @AlexandreFillatre no actually I am trying my hand in it for the first time. Am I missing a handler configuration?

Comment: @ElenaChubukina I tried using that , but it throws 404 error. I would like to configure something that would also work globally, not only locally.

Comment: My bet is that you missed the package-scan configuration, so your handler is never registered. Could you share your `spring-config.xml` file please ?

Comment: @AlexandreFillatre Added spring-config file.

Comment: Can you post the startup logs ? If you controller is in the `com.mmt.controller` package, your configuration looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go.

First of all, you need create `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and put necessary spring configuration here and then put it under `classpath:WEB-INF/`, so the full path is `classpath:WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml`, which contains following settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema    /mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-    context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c" />
</beans>
```

Where `a.b.c` is base package of your controller `MyPortController`. This configuration will tell spring to scan `bean`s(here are `controller`s) from specified packages automatically.

Attention please, why its name is `dispatcher-servlet.xml`? That's because spring will load configuration that named start with `<servlet-name/>` and end with `-servlet.xml`. Otherwise, you should specify it in your `servlet` setting as following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

It should work, enjoy it.

Comment: my mistake that I did not put up my dispatcher-servlet before. I am having trouble with servlet mapping requests url. I have posted all my files above, so if you can help with that,it would be of great help.

Comment: Please add `@ResponseBody` together with `@RequestMapping` on method `searchbyid`, otherwise, return value will be treated as redirect view.